# Ассоциативный массив со значением массив

Tags: php

Всем привет. Пытаюсь создать ассоциативный массив со значением массив. Есть куча данных мне нужно оттуда достать только определенные значения и сохранить в отдельном массиве.

```
while ($object = $res->GetNext()) {
        $arCity[$ob["NAME"]] = ["COUNT" => $object["NAME"]["COUNT"] + $ob["ELEMENT_CNT"]];
        if ($ob["PICTURE"]) {
            $arCity[$object["NAME"]] = ["PICTURE" => $ob["PICTURE"]];
        }
    }
```

Суть в том что мне нужно в count сохранить сумму значения из массива с ключом ELEMENT_CNT. А в PICTURE ссылку на картинку. Но что-то происходит не так.

Comment: `$ob` != `$object`

Comment: Если `$ob` это какая-то внешняя переменная - не из цикла - приведите код ее получения.